# How to draw line parallel to a line and tangent to a circle?

Tags: asymptote

Suppose a line is given in asymptote and a circle is also there. How can I draw a line tangent to circle parallel to the given line?

Comment: If you draw a line from the center of the circle and perpendicular to the given line, it will intersect the circle at the point of tangency (on both sides).  Alas, I don't know how to do that in asymptote.

Comment: @JohnKormylo asymptote has a geometry package which has a `perpendicular` function. I used that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am by no means an expert in Asymptote, so there are probably much more elegant ways to do this, but here is one possible solution:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\begin{document}
\begin{asy}
size(233, 144);
pair a = (-20, 80);
pair b = (100, 42);
path c = scale(50) * unitcircle;
draw(a .. b); draw(c);
real t = dirtime(c, a-b);
draw(shift(point(c, t)) * shift(-0.5a - 0.5b) * (a..b), red);
\end{asy}
\end{document}
```

I put this in a file called `t.asy` and compiled it with

```
lualatex t && asy t-1 && lualatex t
```

(YMMV depending on your set up...)

Comment: Shouldn't there be two tangents?

Comment: @Shiv Since you provided no code or anything, I think you should look at the code above, and in particular on `real t = dirtime(c, a-b);`, and try to understand how it works and how it can be adapted to give a second one.

Comment: @mickep It is part of a larger problem but I understand the code after looking up doc for `dirtime`. @Thruston thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Do you mind a suggestion from your code? Run on http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/ `size(233,144);
pair A = (-20, 80);
pair B = (100, 42);
path cir = scale(50)*unitcircle;
draw(A--B,blue); 
draw(cir);
real t = dirtime(cir,A-B);
pair M = point(cir,t);

draw(M+.5(A-B)--M-.7(A-B), red);
dot("$M$",align=NE,M,red);
dot("$A$",align=W,A,blue);
dot("$B$",align=E,B,blue);`

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have done for the actual problem.

```
settings.outformat = "png";
defaultpen(fontsize(14pt));
import geometry;

size(16cm);

pair a = (0, 1.5);
pair b = (-1, 0);
pair c = (1, 0);

show(triangle(a,b,c), La="", Lb="", Lc="", 0.7*green);
circle i = incircle(triangle(a,b,c));
draw(i, 0.5*green+0.8*blue);
pair c1[] = intersectionpoints(i, line(a, b));
line p1 = perpendicular(c1[0], line(a,b));
pair c2[] = intersectionpoints(i, p1);
line t1 = tangent(i, c2[0]);
pair p2 = intersectionpoint(t1, line(b, c));
pair p3 = intersectionpoint(t1, line(a, c));
draw(p2 -- p3, 0.7*green);
pair c1[] = intersectionpoints(i, line(b, c));
line p1 = perpendicular(c1[0], line(b,c));
pair c2[] = intersectionpoints(i, p1);
line t1 = tangent(i, c2[1]);
pair p2 = intersectionpoint(t1, line(a, b));
pair p3 = intersectionpoint(t1, line(a, c));
draw(p2 -- p3, 0.7*green);
pair c1[] = intersectionpoints(i, line(a, c));
line p1 = perpendicular(c1[0], line(a,c));
pair c2[] = intersectionpoints(i, p1);
line t1 = tangent(i, c2[0]);
pair p2 = intersectionpoint(t1, line(a, b));
pair p3 = intersectionpoint(t1, line(b, c));
draw(p2 -- p3, 0.7*green);
```

which gives following diagram.

[image]

Comment: Hmm, I realise that you are clarifying what you wanted here, but I am not sure that this is really an answer to the actual question you asked.   So there is a risk it will get deleted.  Maybe you should ask a new question?

Comment: @Thruston not really. It shows an alternate solution to draw tangent to the circle.

Answer (score 0):

**Tangent to a circle: with given direction**

One more Asymptote solution, additional to Thurston's answer. First time I learn that `length` (or `time`) of a circle is `4`.

[image]

```
// tangent to a circle: with given direction
// http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
unitsize(1cm); 
pair A=(-1,4), B=(5,1.5); 
path cir=scale(2.5)*unitcircle; 
real t=dirtime(cir,A-B); 
write("The length of any circle is ",length(cir));
pair M = point(cir,t);  
pair P = point(cir,t+length(cir)/2);  
draw(A--B,blue);  
draw(cir); 
draw(M+.4(A-B)--M-.5(A-B), red);
draw(P+.4(A-B)--P-.5(A-B), red);
dot("$M$",align=NE,M,red); 
dot("$P$",align=SW,P,red); 
dot("$A$",align=W,A,blue); 
dot("$B$",align=E,B,blue);
```